# Duplicate Zip Entry Between Dependency and Jar

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I know variants of this question have been asked before, but I've failed to find an answer that suits my need. I am currently trying to run a project in Android Studio that uses 2 other libraries - one of which has TwoWayView as part of its Jar, and the other which uses it via the dependecies / compile in Gradle. They are on the same level of the project (i.e. one is **not** a submodule of the other). Is there any way I can quickly resolve the duplicate zip error? From what I can tell, there is no easy way to exclude a module from a jar. I am not opposed to restructuring the libraries to be submodules of each other if need be.

Comment: the one that gets it via gradle dependencies could use `provided` instead of `compile`. It would build against the lib, but not include it in its packaging.

Comment: then why you need both libs if it's same?

Comment: @njzk2 unfortunately provided only works for jars and not dependencies from what I understand.